# Is the finite topology of an endomorphism ring Noetherian if the elements of its base satisfy the ACC

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Given a left R-module M  over some ring R, the finite topology on its endomorphism ring E=End(M) is defined by defining the neighborhoods of zero as the sets 
$$U(x_1,\ldots , x_n) = \{ f\in E \mid f(x_1)=\cdots = f(x_n)=0\}$$
for any choice $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in M$.

The open sets are then defined to be those subsets $\mathcal{O}\subseteq E$ such that for any $f\in \mathcal{O}$ there exist $x_1\ldots, x_n \in M$ with $f+U(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.

My question is whether it is enough for the finite topology to be Noetherian: i.e. Do all ascending chains of open subsets become stationary if all ascending chains of neighborhoods become stationary?

Comment: I added in clarification that you were talking about ascending chains, because certainly we aren't talking about *all* chains.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a Noetherian topological ring need not be Noetherian as a topological space. For example, in $\mathbf Z_p$, the set $\mathbf Z_p-\{0\}$ is open but not compact, because it has the infinite disjoint open cover
$$\mathbf Z_p-\{0\} = (\mathbf Z_p-p\mathbf Z_p) \cup ( p\mathbf Z_p-p^2\mathbf Z_p) \cup ( p^2 \mathbf Z_p-p^3\mathbf Z_p) \cup \dots$$

So, to find a counter-example coming from the finite topology, we just have to find an example of a pair $(R,M)$ such that, as a topological ring, $\text{End}_R(M) \cong \mathbf Z_p$. This is straightforward if one knows that $\mathbf Q_p/\mathbf Z_p$ (which is the $p$-component of $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$), as an abelian group, has $\text{End}(\mathbf Q_p/\mathbf Z_p) = \mathbf Z_p$, where the finite topology on the left coincides with the *p*-adic topology on the right.

Comment: Interesting: naturally open sets in Noetherian topological spaces have to be compact, so this space isn't Noetherian. And then the neighborhoods turn out to be the same as in the $I$-adic topology of a Noetherian ring. (Comments of someone new to Noetherian spaces.) +1 because I find this interesting and plausibly correct, although I haven't verified all details first hand :S Thanks for the interesting answer to this question!

Comment: @rschwieb My pleasure!

Comment: @Bruno Thanks a lot for the interesting answer!

Comment: @PedroRuiva You are welcome! Don't forget to accept answers you are satisfied with :)